# How to build custom url with GET PARAMETERS in Django template?

Tags: django

I am trying to build a simple e-commerce website and now I am stuck. I want to define href attribute of anchor tag where it should point to url like:

```
/abc?param1=value1
```

but it should also make sure that if my current url already is /abc/param1=somevalue then it should update the url to /abc/param1=value1.

Now, another problem is that the href should be able to handle multiple params like:

```
/abc?param1=value1&param2=value2...
```

I cannot find a topic to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Dou you want this in BAckend or in the Frotend? if it is frontend then you can append new Parameters to the URL with JavaScript.

Comment: I want it in frontend if possible through Django (say some template tag) otherwise backend.